How to Customize NetSuite bin Transfer form
I'm currently working on customizing the bin transfer form in NetSuite, and I'm having trouble finding where to make the necessary changes. Specifically, I need to:
Add custom fields to the bin transfer form.
Modify the layout of the form.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here are the steps I've taken so far:
Navigated to Customization > Forms > Transaction Forms.
Looked through the available forms but couldn't find the specific bin transfer form.
Looked through file cabinet searching for the js.
Searched through SuiteAnswers and NetSuite documentation without much success.
